# Cordova iframe webview switching between landscape and portrait - page resize

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, orientation

I have a cordova application that makes use of an iframe to display content.
When the iframe page loads, the content displays correctly in terms of size, when I rotate the phone to landscape, the iframe and content responds correctly, but when I turn the phone to portrait again, the iframe content remains landscape sized.

This only occurs using iOS, the android version works fine.

I am able to detect when an orientation change is made, but I cannot influence the iframe to change.
The iframes, html is generated.

Has anyone dealt with this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

You could try refreshing the iframe URL whenever there is an orientation change, or disable the screen rotation alltogether in the Cordova app to avoid this error.